# All Trello cards, from every board, in a single calendar

Tags: trello, calendar

With Microsoft shutting down Sunrise Calendar, which was the only one having a flawless integration with Trello, I am looking for an alternative. I DON'T want to download the Outlook app, I don't need another mail app.

As of now, I have dozens of Trello boards (one for every project or client I follow) and I have some cards with due dates scattered all around. **I need to see all my due dates, from all my Trello boards, in a single calendar without having to grab the iCal feeds every single time, for every single board I created.**

I already tried: http://calendar-for-trello.com/app/month but clearly this tool is not mature enough to do the job, plus no smartphone app.

All the other calendar apps I've tried don't have an integration like Sunrise Calendar used to have, and it looks like IFTTT and Zapier don't allow me to create a calendar event triggered by adding or updating a due date to any card.

How are people going to sort out this problem once Sunrise Calendar is shut down once and for all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Kin](http://kin.today/), a calendar app currently in beta, offers a Trello integration similar to Sunrise Calendar.

[image: Trello on Kin]

An iOS app is currently in the works. You can check the status of the mobile app and other developments on [Kin's public road map](https://trello.com/b/RXCPcX7U/kin-public-roadmap).